# Ardhanarishwaras creation

Tags: shiva, vishnu

Who created Ardhanarishwara?
I have taken the case that Ardhanarishwara created Shiva and Vishnu.[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardhanarishvara
Refer to this link for information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your question? It is very unclear.